# Reconnect another tty on docker container

Tags: docker

I want to enter a docker container running multiple tty

but I executed `docker attach` then I could only one tty.

For example, /dev/tty1 and /dev/tty2 are running,
I could only attach /dev/tty2, but I could not attach /dev/tty1

How can I connect /dev/tty1?

Answer (score 1):

You can do `docker exec -it YOUR-CONTAINER` to create a new session inside the running container.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Comment: sorry, I want to know how is able to access the multiple detached session. By `docker exec -it`, we can launch new session on the running docker  as you said, but in the case of already launched session in the docker container, how does we access it?